# Simple text slider in HTML w/ CSS

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel

Good morning, everyone!

I have realised (just now) that i have never ever done sliders before, so i am a little confused on how to implement them into my project.

I need to have my text in the middle, two arrows (left and right) and balls below (so you can jump to wanted slide). There are no images.

The thing is that after a brief Googling session i saw a lot of suggestions to use special libraries, etc. I am sure it can be done in pure HTML & CSS.

The desired look: [image]

I would really appreciate any kind of related literature and/or examples (jsfiddle, etc).

Thank you!

Comment: This is too broad and therefore off topic (also off toopic to ask us to recommend tutorials and tools) but I usually use this plugin https://kevinbatdorf.github.io/codaslider/.  Here is a pen for a pure css slider: https://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/rtpnE

Comment: I don't think anyone will just code this for you, but I use this which can achieve this result: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Trying to achieve this in pure HTML + CSS will not be worth the trouble.  It'll be prone to breaking, a huge time investment, and provide little in return compared to an established third party plugin.  You're much better off finding a trusted third party plugin to achieve what you want.  There are many to choose from.  The only time I could see developing one of these by hand being worth while is as a learning experience, and I wouldn't trust using the end result in a production environment.

Comment: Here's a place to start if you're doing it as a learning exercise https://jsfiddle.net/Lbw8roo4/1/